# Cassandra read in loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cassandra

I am facing some difficulty in deciding how to implement a read operation using cassandra.

The case is that I have an array of id's, let's call it idArray.
After making the read, I am pushing the result in a result array (resultArray)

Now my problem being that would such a code be efficient at all ?

```
`for(i;i<idAArray.length;i++)
{   
    let query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE \"id\"=?idArray[i]" 
    client.execute(query)
    .then(result => resultArray.push(result));
}`
```

If running in parallel is an option, please specify how exactly ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you provide callback to the `execute` call, then the code will be asynchronous, and you can issue multiple requests in parallel:

```
client.execute(query, [ 'someone' ], function(err, result) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0].email);
});
```

Depending on number of queries that you need to execute, you may need to tune [connection pooling](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.5/features/connection-pooling/) to allow more in-fligh requests per connection. It's also recommended to prepare your query.

More information is in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.4/#basic-usage).

Comment: I get the asynchronous part. Can't imagine doing it in synchronous mode anyway :). 
However, let's say I have an array of about 5000 id's and though the read operation doesn't take any more than a few milliseconds, is it a good way to read from cassandra still ?

Comment: Yes, you may need to throttle although - that's why I mentioned the connection pooling.